# Why does the Obx (from GetX package) not work in function with Rx as parameter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

Consider this code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get_rx/src/rx_types/rx_types.dart';
import 'package:get/get_state_manager/src/rx_flutter/rx_obx_widget.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  RxBool get moreThan5 => (counter > 5).obs;
  RxInt counter = 0.obs;

  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: [
        test1(),
        test2(moreThan5),
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              counter++;
            },
            child: Obx(() => Text(counter.string)))
      ]),
    ));
  }

  Widget test1() {
    return Obx(() => Text(moreThan5.string));
  }

  Widget test2(RxBool rx) {
    return Obx(() => Text(rx.string));
  }
}
```

As expected you get this output at startup:

[image]

And when clicking the number it goes up. When reaching 6 it turns into:

[image]

I was actually kind of surprised it would work for the `test1` because of the way `moreThan5` is constructed, but that's not my question here. My question is: Why doesn't it work for the `test2`? It's exactly the same code, except for the Rx coming from a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have it figured out. The reason why `test1` even works is also the reason why `test2` doesn't work. Because `moreThan5` is accessed inside `test1` the getter is called at that point. In the getter it accesses `counter`. As a result, the Obx there is actually also observing `counter`, triggering everytime `counter` changes, not only when `moreThan5` goes from `false` to `true`.

In `test2` the getter is accessed before it's passed to the function, so the `Obx` inside `test2` only observes the `RxBool`, which actually never really changes, because accessing `moreThan5` creates a new `RxBool` every time it's accessed